# When are two pregeometries equivalent?

Tags: lo.logic, discrete-geometry, model-theory, matroid-theory

Some model theorists / combinatorial geometers like to think about pregeometries (matroids with a weak finiteness condition) associated to first-order theories. But the usual way of constructing a pregeometry is not invariant under biinterpretability in any obvious sense. Is there a suitable notion of equivalence of pregeometries such that biinterpretable theories have equivalent pregeometries?

More precisely, if $T$ is a theory, then by "the pregeometry associated to $T$" I mean the following. Let $U$ be a monster model of $T$, and consider the algebraic closure operator on (the home sort of) $U$. This forms a pregeometry, the one I have in mind. So the question is

**Question:** Is there a notion of equivalence of pregeometries such that the pregeometry associated to a theory in the above sense is invariant under biinterpretability?

But trying to compare the pregeometries of biinterpretable theories is immediately problematic: biinterpretable theories could consider different sorts to be the "home sort". So it's not clear how to even produce a map of geometries (in the obvious sense) from an interpretation. Even if a map is produced, it seems unlikely to be an isomorphism.

Introductions to this topic seem to provide a candidate notion: a "geometry" is a pregeometry such that the closure of a singleton set is itself. Every pregeometry can be quotiented to yield a canonical geometry. But biinterpretable theories need not have isomorphic geometries -- in fact, the quotient seems even more problematic since biinterpretable theories need not agree on what the singletons are. So this doesn't seem to get us anywhere.

Comment: Algebraic closure does not, in general, satisfy the exchange property.

Comment: Good point. I guess I should assume that $T$ is stable.

Comment: I don't think stability would do. The theories where acl satisfies exchange are called "geometric" in some papers. (Actually I think they also require the elimination of $\exists^\infty$ quantifier.) Strongly minimal and O-minimal theories are geometric.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I definitely had the wrong impression of the scope of this story. So let's assume that $T$ is geometric.